# Pausing and Resuming CAEmitterLayer Multiple of Times

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation, caemitterlayer

I have a `CAEmitterLayer` instance that I want to pause and then resume **multiple times**.

I have found various ways to do this using two `CAEmitterLayer` extension functions:

```
public func pause() {
    speed = 0.0 // Freeze existing cells.
    timeOffset = convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: self)
    lifetime = 0.0 // Stop creating new cells.
}
```

and

```
public func resume() {
    speed = 1.0
    beginTime = convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: self) - timeOffset
    timeOffset = 0.0
    lifetime = 1.0
}
```

The first occasion of using `emitterLayer.pause()` and `emitterLayer.resume()` works perfectly.

**However**, from the second occasion onwards, whenever I use `emitterLayer.pause()`, the `emitterCells` jump slightly forward in time.

Can anybody out there help me resolve this jumping problem, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I needed to adjust the `timeOffset` in the `pause()` method. This is a working extension for pausing and resuming a `CAEmitterLayer` instance:

```
extension CAEmitterLayer {

    /**
     Pauses a CAEmitterLayer.
     */
    public func pause() {
        speed = 0.0 // Freeze the CAEmitterCells.
        timeOffset = convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: self) - beginTime
        lifetime = 0.0 // Produce no new CAEmitterCells.
    }

    /**
     Resumes a paused CAEmitterLayer.
     */
    public func resume() {
        speed = 1.0 // Unfreeze the CAEmitterCells.
        beginTime = convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: self) - timeOffset
        timeOffset = 0.0
        lifetime = 1.0 // Produce CAEmitterCells at previous rate.
    }

}
```

Use as:

```
var emitterLayer = CAEmitterLayer()
/// Configure as required

emitterLayer.pause()
emitterLayer.resume()
```